# Explain why we use this formula to calculate total resistance

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Why do we use this formula to find the total resistance? Lets say we have three resistors in a parallel circuit

$$R_t = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}}$$

Where does it come from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resistors in series vs parallel](http://physics.stackexchange.com/qu/90830/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about current flow.
If we take each individual resistor and determine the current for the applied voltage, we get: $$I_T=\frac {V}{R_1} +\frac {V}{R_2} + ...$$
Dividing everything by the voltage give us: 
$$\frac {I_T}{V}=\frac {1}{R_1} +\frac {1}{R_2} + ...$$
Which is the same as:
$$\frac {1}{R_{eq}}=\frac {1}{R_1} +\frac {1}{R_2} + ...$$
We now need to invert both sides, which gives:
$${R_{eq}}=\frac {1}{\frac {1}{R_1} +\frac {1}{R_2} + ...}$$

Comment: I do think it's important to think about the currents as summing to a total current, so better would be starting with `I[T] = I1 + I2 + ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is derived from the [the formula for calculating total resistance in a parallel circuit](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circuits/Lesson-4/Parallel-Circuits)

$$\frac{1}{R_t} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}$$

taking its inverse gives:

$$R_t = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we use this formula to find the total resistance?

Because parallel connected *[conductances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance)* sum just as series connected *resistances*.

Ohm's law is

$$V_R = RI_R $$

The [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28electrical_circuits%29#Constitutive_relations) of Ohm's law is

$$I_G = GV_G $$

Since, for parallel connected circuit elements, the voltage across is identical, it follows that, for parallel connected conductances

$$I_{total} = V\left(G_1 + G_2 + G_3 + \;... \right)$$

But

$$G = \frac{1}{R} $$

thus

$$I_{total} = V\left(\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3} + \;...\right) $$

or

$$\frac{V}{I_{total}} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3} + \;...} = R_{eq}$$